# How to use foreach loop in sql queries in laravel

Tags: sql, laravel, mariadb, laravel-6

I don't know the no. of columns in a table. I can get the column listing from query like this

```
$data = DB::getSchemaBuilder()->getColumnListing(table);
```

Now, I want to insert values into this table from form requests. I stored values of these in an object values.

```
foreach($data as $key => $data){ 
            $value = $_GET["$data"];}
```

and then i used the following sql query

```
DB::insert("INSERT INTO `$table` foreach ($data as $data){ (`$data`) } VALUES foreach ($value as $value){ ('$value') }");
```

Please correct the sql query written here

Answer (score 0):

in laravel you can use `table` function of `DB`:

```
DB::table('users')->insert(
    ['email' => 'john@example.com', 'votes' => 0]
);
```

for your code:

```
DB::table($table)->insert($data);
```

[Laravel-Database: Query Builder / Inserts](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#inserts)

Answer (score 0):

You can't do what you desire at the sql level, you will need to build out a key/value array of what you want to insert.

```
$insertValues = [];
foreach($data as $key => $columnName){ 
  $inserValues[$key] = $_GET[$columnName];
}

DB::table($table)
   ->insert($insertValues);
```

You should also reexamine your use of $_GET. Laravel makes it easy to inject a request object into your controller and retrieve posted/putted data from it. https://laravel.com/docs/master/requests

e.g. `$request->input($columnName);` instead of `$_GET[$columnName]`

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks alot , but there is still a problem in this, the column names were now 0,1,2,.... i tried to fix this but there was an error saying array to string conversion. can you help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: what is the output of dd(DB::getSchemaBuilder()->getColumnListing(table));?

Comment: dd works perfectly all the column names were dumped.

Comment: $insertValues = [];
        foreach($data as $key => $columnName){ 
          $insertValues[$key] = $_GET[$columnName];
        }


        $columns = [];
        foreach($data as $key => $data){ 
          $columns[$key] = $data;
        }
        DB::table($table)
           ->insert([$columns => $insertValues,]);


I used the above code and it returned illegal offset type error